# Spring Boot war to docker

Tags: spring, docker, spring-boot, tomcat, war

my docker file looks like this:

```
FROM tomcat:8.5-alpine
VOLUME /tmp
COPY SNAPSHOT.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/app.war
RUN sh -c 'touch /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/app.war'
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "-c", "java -Dspring.profiles.active=docker -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -jar /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/app.war" ]
```

Everything is ok when deploying it. I am using docker compose because I have 2 containers: one for tomcat and one for mongodb.

docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```
tomcatserver:
    image: myimage
    container_name: tomcat
    ports:
        - 8080
    hostname: tomcat
    links:
        - mongodb:mongo

mongodb:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongo
    ports:
        - 27017
    hostname: mongo
    volumes:
        - $HOME/data/mongo:/data/db
    restart: always
```

So everything works fine except my static resources. They are located in

> /src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/

When I compile it with

> ./gradlew bootRun

it works fine, I can access these static resources but when uploaded to docker they are inaccessible.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you try to place the static reources at `/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/static`?

Comment: Should I access it the same way I do when using bootRun: "host:port/index.html" If yes, it doesn't work :(

Comment: It was only a guess, sorry about not being helpful

Comment: can you check with container logs once `docker logs <docker-id>`. I suspect boot app itself is not coming up for some reason. Logs will atleast isolate that problem.

Comment: I will see the logs but what I want to say is that the spring boot application starts, I can do everything that my app provides without the static content

Comment: I also tried adding the generated war file to my tomcat on my machine and it works, I can access the static resources